# Prevent phone from saving an image after upload

Tags: android, ios, html, image, upload

I have a website with a simple HTML upload field. Users submit photos, that they take from their camera app. For security reasons these images cannot be stored on the device once they are uploaded. Is there a way to force the image to be deleted after upload or prevent it from saving all together? it works on iPhone and some Android devices but my LG G4, saves the image to my gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, the web browser security model does not allow for pages to have arbitrary access to destructive changes on the filesystem.